# Visual studio nuget and project references dependencies

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, installshield

I have a special case of Visual studio environment and don't know how dependencies are resolved in this case and especially how content files are dispatched.

I have a solution with "Project A" (class library, SDK style csproj), "Project B" (class library, SDK style csproj) and "Project C" (VSTO solution, so old csproj style). All projects are using PackageReference.

"A" builds its NuGet package, "B" references "A" and "C" references "B".
"A" has content files needed by "C" to run so "B" specifies that "1" content files are not in PrivateAssets.

Then, I have another solution with a "Project D" (class library, SDK style) that uses "A" NuGet package. "D" also has content files and build its own NuGet package.

Finally, "B" uses the "D" package.

How is this situation handled within my first solution ?
How can I be sure that, If i change a content file in the "A" without updating "D", project "B" (and then "C") will have the updated content file from project reference ?

Note: In fact, this use-case is really simplified. I have many native libraries in my NuGet packages structure that are shared across projects and my main problem is that I also have an installshield project in the first solution that, when building the MSI, contains duplicates of files and I'm not sure of which file will be really installed on the client computer.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Based on your description I'm not sure if it's a problem with installshield. Maybe you can create an issue in the Revenera Community.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did, but I also created an issue in november 2021 and it never had an answer... I really don't trust in Revenera and I really thinking of quitting this sh*t to a custom installer ^^